# Active track mission sample does not work in Mavic Air

Tags: android, github, dji-sdk

The Active track sample provided in the GitHub by the DJI-SDK tutorials does not work with **Mavic Air**. It work fine with Mavic Pro. Please find the Sample provided in the below [link](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-Phantom4Missions)

Is there anything that needs to be modified with the sample so as to make it work in Mavic Air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The tutorial of active track provided in the [link](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-Phantom4Missions) is not supported the Mavic air now. The sample app will be updated recently.
2. Mavic air supports auto sensing, enabling auto sensing is the pre-condition of starting active track.
3. If this issue blocked your work, you can make the sample work for Mavic Air by adding a button for `enableAutoSensing` or `enableAutoSensingForQuickShot`.

Comment: Is it the same way for Mavic 2 Zoom and Mavic 2 Pro? i.e. Is Enabling Auto sensing a pre-condition for Mavic 2 models?